# Are there any distinct situations that an EV is not a good fit for?

Tags: electric-vehicles, usa

With the [new U.S. tax regulations](https://www.consumerreports.org/cars/hybrids-evs/electric-vehicles-that-qualify-for-new-ev-tax-credit-a9310530660/) supporting purchase of electric vehicles (EVs), there will be many new first-time EV owners in the near future.

What are considerations for someone planning to buy their first EV? Are there any distinct situations that an EV is not a good fit for?

Comment: Don't forget the other side of the scale: situations where walking, public transport or cycling are better. Sustainably speaking, cars/trucks are very much the fallback position when none of those can be used.

Answer (score 1):

They are a non-starter for me. One trip I make is 80 miles ( 160 round trip), much of it in Houston, so chance of getting struck in traffic with need of AC. You will find the AC ( or heat) needs about as much power as moving the car.

Comment: I agree, intense weather is a concern. Also the availability of charging stations in the area. And your trip length is significant, I understand where you're coming from!
I'm a fan of EV's still myself, but I know they won't be a fit for everyone.

Comment: Where did you get the data on AC?

Comment: Internal reports from Amoco engine lab . Speeds like 40 and 50 mph with little wind resistance require only low horse power.